# "Remote Control" Rockbox plugin?

Tags: plugins, mp3-player, rockbox

I recently updated Rockbox to version 3.4 on my Sandisk Sansa e280, and I've noticed a new plugin in the Applications section called `remote_control`. Opening it reveals a visibly non-functional settings menu. What does this do? Does it control the new desktop music player USB remote functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to bypass the USB Mass Storage Connection. Just hold the center button on a menu item, like remote_control when you plug your sansa into the computer. Your sansa will charge, but will not appear under my computer. You can use Rockbox as if the sansa was not plugged into a computer.

Comment: Now, if I had heard of this earlier, I could have put the remote control to good use... oh well, I'll find a use for it later.

Comment: But hey! That's not what the remote control is. See my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a sample [HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) input to host application, from a quick Google search. Interesting. See also [this page](http://www.rockbox.org/mail/archive/rockbox-dev-archive-2009-06/0367.shtml) at rockbox.org and [this Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=site%3Arockbox.org+remote_control&btnG=Google+Search).

**Update:** I upgraded not too long ago to 3.4 on my Sansa e240 and got to try remote_control out. On my Dell 1501 under Windows XP, I was able to adjust the system volume with the scroll wheel, mute the system sound with the middle button (select), and use the playback buttons to control foobar2000 (foobar had to be the active window, but that might be changeable).